# Control Flow issue: Python function called but not executed

Tags: python, control-flow

I have the strangest problem I have ever met in my life.

I have a part of my code that looks like this:

```
class AzureDevOpsServiceError(Exception):
    pass


skip = ["auto"]


def retrieve_results():
    print(variable_not_defined)
    ... # some useful implementation


if not "results" in skip:
    try:
        print("before")
        retrieve_results()
        print("after")
    except AzureDevOpsServiceError as e:
        print(f"Error raised: {e}")
```

Obviously, this shall raise an error because `variable_not_defined` is, well, not defined.

However, for some strange reasons, the code executes correctly and prints

```
before
after
```

I have tried to call the function with an argument (`retrieve_results(1234)`) or adding an argument in the function (`def retrieve_results(arg1)` and `retrieve_results()`): both modifications will trigger an exception, so obviously the function is called.

Anyone has got a similar issue and knows what happens?

FYI: this is actually what my implementation looks like:

```
from azure.devops.exceptions import AzureDevOpsServiceError
import logging


def _retrieve_manual_results(connect: Connectivity, data: DataForPickle) -> None:
    """Retrieve the list of Test Results"""
    print("G" + ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg)
    logger = connect.logger

    data.run_in_progress = [165644]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = ...
    connect = ...
    data = ...

    if not "results" in p.options.skip:
        try:
            print("........B.........")
            _retrieve_manual_results(connect, data)
            print("........A.........")
        except AzureDevOpsServiceError as e:
            logging.error(f"E004: Error while retrieving Test Results: {e}")
            logging.debug("More details below...", exc_info=True)
```

Comment: I get NameError: name 'variable_not_defined' is not defined on python 3.7.3 running on windows vs code.

Comment: I run the same code it throws an undefined error.

Comment: Is this executed on a server in a special environment (as the "Azure" suggests)?

Comment: then maybe my computer has some problem?

Comment: Seems like a caching/environment error or some such.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: a run on plain MS Windows with cmd (or msys).

Comment: @gmds: what could I could I do to refresh the cache? I tried deleting the .pyc files but does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: It would appear your code does not run "correctly", since it prints `before` and `after` but it prints nothing where you would have it print whatever the value of `variable_not_defined` is. Since there is nothing that prints, well, nothing - I am assuming you changed the original code and output and are not providing the actual situation, which may be preventing us from actually answering your question.

Comment: Also, pet peeve, not relevant to your problem: it's not "a code", to any programmer that sounds like "I have a money". You can have "some code" or "a piece of code", etc. or you can have "code", but "a code" typically refers to something else.

Comment: see if it is defined? try: variable_not_defined except NameError: print('oh well')

Comment: @Grismar I personally find "Does anyone know any codes to do this" the worst.

Comment: @gmds ... with a question like "I have this exercise at school and I need to do this." and not even an attempt to solve the issue ;)

Comment: @gmds as a pro-programmer, I have all the best codes to do all your thats. ;-)

Comment: @Grismar Good for you!  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted by @gmds, it was a problem of cache.

Deleting the **.pyc** file didn't do much.

However, I have found a solution:

1. Renaming the function (e.g. adding `_`)
2. Running the program
3. Renaming back (i.e. removing `_` in the previous example)

Now, the issue is solved.

If anyone knows what is going behind the scene I am very interested.

Comment: Any chance it was calling a different function with the same name?

Comment: @KennyOstrom: no, I checked and I had only 2 occurences of this name: implementation and call